# Посоветуйте PHP Query Builder для postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

Посоветуйте PHP Query Builder для postgresql. И собственно стоит ли игра свеч, на высоко нагруженных проектах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прочитайте эти статуи или найдите подобные погуглив.

https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/248845/

http://eax.me/postgresql-vs-mysql/

Вы пробовали работать с php PDO class ?

```
$dbh = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=$dbname;host=$host", $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

В конструкторе указываете соединение с postgresql и вперед 
http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.connections.php

Comment: Да вот как раз мигрирую сразу на pdo и пытаюсь понять, нужно ли оборачивать его во что то еще и нет. Спасибо за ссылки, буду изучать.

Comment: если считаете что я как то помог вам,то прошу поставить галочку или нажать на стрелочку вверх  возле отвeта,спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Если в проекте предполагается сложная бизнес-логика, я бы отдал предпочтение [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) - это полноценная ORM.

Имеет в арсенале очень мощный и удобный (на мой взгляд) QueryBuilder.

По поводу использования в highload - тут все упирается в архитектуру проекта. Без дополнительных сведений и деталей невозможно определить подойдет какое либо решение или нет.